# Custom_Filters_Score with Nested Object and Script

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use a value in a nested object to boost my rank based on the [custom_filters_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query/) method. So, a match is not required, but if it does, it will boost the rank. Normally, one can hardcode a boost, but I'd like to use a [script field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/modules/scripting/) based on the value in the nested document that would have matched.

If I hardcode a value, say 1000, I can see the impact on the score. However, it's as though ES is unable to make sense of popularity key as it gives it gives it no boost.

Documents look like so with search_terms being type=nested, simple two keys and two values:

```
{
"name":"colorful light blue things that make developers wild"
"search_terms":[
    {
        "a_term":"colorful",
        "popularity":33433
    },
    {
        "a_term":"light blue",
        "popularity":343
    }
]
"other_keys":"stuff"
}
```

Here is the example the custom_filters_score query

```
{
    "query":{
        "custom_filters_score":{
        --query:{} would be here--
        ,"filters":[
            {
                "filter":{
                    "nested":{
                        "path":"search_terms"
                        ,"query": {
                            "match": {
                                "a_term": "light blue"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                --here is my problem area
                "script":"doc['search_terms.popularity'].value"
                -- this would work, hard coded value
                "script":"1000"           
             }
         ]
     }    
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access nested documents fields while iterating over them. In your query you are trying to access nested field outside the nested query. Try something like this:

```
"query": {
   "nested": {
      "score_mode": "total",
      "path": "search_terms",
      "query": {
          "function_score": {
              "query": {
                  "match": {
                      "a_term": "light blue"
                  }
               },
              "script_score": {
                  "script": "doc['search_terms.popularity'].value"
              },
              "boost_mode": "replace"
          }
      }
   }
}
```